# How to name a folder as the user's IP address in PHP

Tags: php

I've searched long and hard for an answer to this question with no luck, hence this question is being asked.

How could I possibly name a folder as the client's IP address? For example:

192.168.0.1 visits my website and I want php to automatically make a folder with the name '192.168.0.1' (I can do the rest such as make a document inside showing logs etc, I just need to know if thats possible).

I've tried using global variables such as the [REMOTE_ADDR] but with no luck, it always shows an error on the webpage.

Comment: You forgot to post the most important information - your code and what error it throws. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` should contain the client's IP address, but there's no guarantee. Also, you should remember that more users can be behind a single IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a directory by using the [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) function as follows:

```
mkdir('path/to/directory')
```

To find out the user's IP address you can use the `'REMOTE_ADDR'` key of the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Basically this will result in the following code:

```
$directory_name = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
mkdir('path/to/' + $directory_name)
```

*Please note that the received IP from `REMOTE_ADDR` can't always be trusted. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003233/1294864) answer for more information about the subject.*

Comment: A folder with '0' is made but not my IP.

Comment: @meherbanulhaq If you do `var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` what does it give you?

Comment: string(3) "::1" - Is what it gives me but the folder name is just '0', shouldn't the folder name be "::1" too?

Comment: Ah, apparently `::1` is the equivalent of `127.0.0.1` for `IPv6` addresses. Perhaps that will get you in some trouble as well when it comes to naming directories, because Windows does not support `:` characters for directory names. Still doesn't quite explain why your directory was created with name `0` however.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:
1. Get the user ip:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

2. Make the directory:

```
mkdir(''.$ip);
```

example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_mkdir.asp)

Comment: Still doesn't work, it does however this time, add a folder with the number '0' instead of giving an error.

Comment: You're better to link to the *actual* manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: try to echo $ip; and see what you receive, before creating a directory.